# html minifier parse error in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, html-parsing

My html file looks like

```
<% for (var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; ++i) {
  var _name = props[i][0];
  var _value = props[i][1]; %>
<p>
  <span class="prop"><%=_name%>&#58;&nbsp;</span><span class="value"><%=_value%></span>
</p>
<% } %>
```

I get a html parse error in the for loop.

> Warning: Command failed:
>   /Users/xx/xx/xxxxx/node_modules/html-minifier/dist/htmlminifier.js
>           throw 'Parse Error: ' + html;
>                                 ^
>   Parse Error:

I don't know what the even means. I checked at the props array it is giving me the correct data.

> props = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]]

The html does give correct values when i print them out static.

```
<p>
  <span class="prop"><%=props[0][0]%>&#58;&nbsp;</span><span class="value"><%=props[0][1]%></span>
</p>
<p>
  <span class="prop"><%=props[1][0]%>&#58;&nbsp;</span><span class="value"><%=props[1][1]%></span>
</p>
<p>
  <span class="prop"><%=props[2][0]%>&#58;&nbsp;</span><span class="value"><%=props[2][1]%></span>
</p>
```

This gives me the required result.

But i want to know how to fix the parse error in the for loop.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095424/minify-html-php

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using a html-minifier on a non-plain html files, with special server tags such as `<%` and `<%=_value%>`. You should use the minification process on only resulting html files from the server, not on templates.